# Issue when using a stored procedure to restore .bak file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a bunch of `.bak` files on the database server, I have created a stored procedure to execute this (currently in master). Eexecuting my stored procedure seems to overwrite my data *almost* correctly, however its missing some recent data that **is included** in the `.bak` file.

If I manually restore the `.bak`, I have all the data, when my stored procedure does it, I am missing some data. I have a hunch its the WITH REPLACE? Without it I get some other errors.

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
ALTER DATABASE dbName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

RESTORE Database dbName 
FROM DISK = N'C:\Backups\Databases\dbName.bak'
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE 'dbName' TO N'C:\Backups\Databases\DATA\dbName.mdf',  
MOVE 'dbName_log' TO N'C:\Backups\Databases\DATA\dbName.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

ALTER DATABASE dbName 
    SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

I am not great with SQL Server, anyone got any guidance on how to resolve my issue?

**Solution**: setting the `FILE = n` I was not specifying it and it assumed by default to be 1 I believe, setting it to 4 (latest backup) resolved my issue

Comment: Is There any Files groups enable in you database ?

Comment: Can you tell us the error you encounter when you use the `WITH REPLACE` keyword ?

Comment: issues with the backup tail log, updated my question with my recent state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are not moving any file group in to particular folder loaction try like this

```
  USE [master]
    ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012_Temp] 
    FROM  DISK = N'D:\Backup\AdventureWorks2012.bak' 
    WITH  FILE = 1,  
    MOVE N'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO N'D:\Backup\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks2012_1.mdf',  
    MOVE N'AdventureWorks2012_Log' TO N'D:\Backup\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks2012_1_Log.ldf',  
    NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Comment: I tried this, my files are now successfully moved to my directory after use FILELISTONLY to grab them, however when my SP invokes the restore it seems to work successfully but i'm still missing data.  If I manually restore the .bak through SSMS GUI the data is present (Same .bak file in both instances)  any other ideas? worth noting: I took this .bak file from another sql instance on the same server

Comment: problem was FILE = 1, when i needed FILE = 4 as my .bak file had multiple backups inside, I was restoring the first one which was very old in comparison to #4

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
RESTORE DATABASE ReportServerSplitCopy FROM
 DISK = 'D:\DBBackups\ReportServer\ReportServer_Split1.bak'
,DISK = 'D:\DBBackups\ReportServer\ReportServer_Split2.bak'
,DISK = 'D:\DBBackups\ReportServer\ReportServer_Split3.bak'
WITH REPLACE ,
MOVE 'ReportServer' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER11\MSSQL\DATA\ReportServerSplitCopy.mdf',
MOVE 'ReportServer_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER11\MSSQL\DATA\ReportServerSplitCopy_log.ldf'
GO
```